# REST API - works in chrome but curl did not work

Tags: http, google-chrome, curl

I am using a web service API. 
`http://www.douban.com/j/app/radio/people?app_name=radio_desktop_win&version=100&user_id=&expire=&token=&sid=&h=&channel=1&type=n`

Typing that address into the chrome, expected result (json file containing song information) could be returned but when using `curl` it failed. (in both case,response code is OK but the response body is not correct in the later case )

Here are the request info dumped using the Chrome developer tool:

```
Request URL:http://www.douban.com/j/app/radio/people?app_name=radio_desktop_win&version=100&user_id=&expire=&token=&sid=&h=&channel=7&type=n
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:zh-CN,zh;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:bid="lwaJyClu5Zg"
Host:www.douban.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
app_name:radio_desktop_win
version:100
user_id:
expire:
token:
sid:
h:
channel:7
type:n
```

However, using that API with curl, i.e `curl http://www.douban.com/j/app/radio/people?app_name=radio_desktop_win&version=100&user_id=&expire=&token=&sid=&h=&channel=7&type=n` will not return expected result.

Even specifying the exactly header as what dumped from Chrome still failed.

```
curl -v -H "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflat,sdcn" -H "Accept-Language:zh-CN,zh;q=0.8" -H "Cache-Control:max-age=0" -H "Connection:keep-alive"  -H "Host:www.douban.com" -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36" http://www.douban.com/j/app/radio/people?app_name=radio_desktop_win&version=100&user_id=&expire=&token=&sid=&h=&channel=7&type=n
```

Below is what print out with `-v` from curl. Seems everything was identical with the request made by Chrome but still the response body is not correct.

> GET /j/app/radio/people?app_name=radio_desktop_win HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
>   Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflat,sdcn
>   Accept-Language:zh-CN,zh;q=0.8
>   Cache-Control:max-age=0
>   Connection:keep-alive
>   Host:www.douban.com

Why this happened? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put quotes around that url in the shell.  Otherwise the `&`s are going to cause trouble.

Another common problem:  you may be using an HTTP proxy with Chrome.  If so, you need to tell curl about this proxy as well.  You can do so by setting the environmental variable `http_proxy`.